# Why is doLayout not working on second click?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using the doLayout function on a window.

```
    var win = new Ext.Window({
    id: 'site-action-window',
    closeAction: 'hide',
    resizable: false,
    layout: 'fit'
});

    function showWin(f) {
    win.removeAll();
    win.add(f);
    win.setSize(400, 150);
    win.setTitle(localize.addLanguage);
    win.show();
    win.doLayout();
}
```

when I call this function for the first time all is working fine.
but once I make a second call I get an error saying "b.getPositionEl().dom is undefined"
from the fire bug.
can anyone explain?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem,

I was destroying the object then trying to call it again from outside the scoop

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Firebug, look at the stack trace.  What's b?  You need to do a little debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **closeAction: 'hide'** when defining your window

```
    var win = new Ext.Window({
    id: 'site-action-window',
    closeAction: 'hide',
    resizable: false,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    layout: 'fit'});
```

When a user closes the window, the window is automatically destroyed - therefore cannot be called again. Using closeAction: 'hide' will change the behavior of the close button from 'close' to 'hide'.

Sources: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Window